# How to add image in <circle> tag

Tags: pointers, dictionary

I am using Google Map and I want to put image in `<circle>` tag. So please guide me how can add image in this part?

[image]

I have mentioned code in below. Please review and reply..

```svg
<g id="map_points">
<circle cx="421" cy="403" r="3.5" fill="#000" style="fill-opacity:0.5" id="map_points_shadow_0"/>
<circle cx="420" cy="402" r="3.5" fill="#FF0000" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="1" id="map_points_0" cursor="pointer" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"/>
<circle cx="366" cy="411" r="3.5" fill="#000" style="fill-opacity:0.5" id="map_points_shadow_1"/>
<circle cx="365" cy="410" r="3.5" fill="#FF0000" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="1" id="map_points_1" cursor="pointer" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"/>
</g>
```

Comment: I edited your message to look the way you presumably wanted. If this is not what you meant, feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the Google Maps Javascript API you are referring to (and not one of the other interfaces such as static maps) then you will need to create `google.maps.Marker` objects.

Using the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/custom-markers) provided by Google as a point of reference you will need to create an instance of the following for each image you want to add to your map. The example below assumes you have created a `google.maps.Map` object and assigned it to a javascript variable called `map`.

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng( -0.127985, 51.507877 ) ;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
    position: location,
    icon: "https://example.com/images/myImage.png",
    map: map
} ) ;
```

As you can see, the `google.maps.Marker` object requires a url pointing to your image and the lat and long as a `google.maps.LatLng` object.

[EDIT]

Just thought I'd drop you a quick example. This might not be exactly what you are after, i.e. list of items to plot, etc but it should give you a fair understanding of placing an image on a Google map and act as a basis for doing your own changes.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <style>
      #map-here {
        width: 400px ;
        height: 400px ;
        border-radius: 3px ;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-here"></div>

    <script>
      function wrapper() {
        addMapWithMarker( {
           'coords': [ 51.507877, -0.127985 ],
           'image': 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/info-i_maps.png',
        }, 'map-here' ) ;

        function addMapWithMarker( args, id ) {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById( id ), {
              zoom: 16,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
              disableDefaultUI: true,
              zoomControl: true,
              mapTypeControl: true,
              scaleControl: false,
              streetViewControl: false,
              rotateControl: false,
              fullscreenControl: false,
              center: { lat: args.coords[0], lng: args.coords[1] },
            }
          ) ;

          var infoMarker = new google.maps.Marker( {
            position: { lat: args.coords[0], lng: args.coords[1] },
            icon: args.image,
            map: map,
            title: "Lord Nelson",
          } );
        }
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<api-key>&libraries=visualization&callback=wrapper"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Replace `<api-key>` with your API key.

[END EDIT]

Comment: If you want to checking my code, so i can send it.. But as per your example its not working

Comment: you want to check html file or js config file ?

Comment: Maybe provide a url if possible? JS Fiddle or similar?